# Check if a process uses microphone with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm interested to check if **any process** (Linux, macOS or Windows) **are using microphone**. I've already found this on [Check if microphone is used by a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427800/check-if-microphone-is-used-by-a-process) but there is no answer.

I need something similar:

```
if process.usesMicrophone():
   do something
```

or

```
if microphone.isActive(process):
   do something
```

Can anybody help me? I'm not interested to record any audio. Just checking if a process uses or doesn't use microphone

Comment: Not the solution, but can be used as reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265634/8595891

Comment: It references about microphones connected by USB... But I want something for every microphone. Thanks anyway